# Regex validate string contains letters and numbers regardless of special characters

Tags: python, regex, passwords, regex-lookarounds

For password validation in Python, I need to make a regex, which validates that passwords contains both letters and numbers. I have this regex:

```
re.match(r"^[A-Za-z]+\d+.*$", password)
```

But if the password contains a special character, then it won't pass. So password for example "MyPassword6" will be ok but "MyPassword-6" not. Also it will not pass if number is on the beginning "6MyPassword".

How to validate a regex with mandatory letters and numbers regardless of their order and regardless of the presence of other special characters?

Thank you!!!

adding *[~!@#$%^&*()_-] didn't help and I can't find other solution :/

Comment: Try using lookaheads. Most relevant to your case is probably positive lookahead, which looks like `(?=x)` (look ahead and see if x can be matched. If not, cancel the match).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression uses two positive lookahead assertions `(?=...)` to ensure that the password contains at least one letter and at least one number. The `.*` symbol in each lookahead assertion means that any characters, including special characters and whitespace can be present in the password, as long as the letters and numbers are also present.

```py
import re

# compile the regular expression
regex = re.compile(r'(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])')

def is_valid_password(password):
    # Check if the password is valid
    return regex.search(password) is not None

password = "@u2_>mypassw#ord123!*-"

if is_valid_password(password):
    print("Valid password")
else:
    print("Invalid password")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following **regex pattern** should work

```
r"^.*[A-Za-z]+.*\d+.*$|^.*\d+.*[A-Za-z]+.*$"
```

#### Explanation:

- `^.*[A-Za-z]+.*\d+.*$` : finds passwords with **letters** before numbers
- `^.*\d+.*[A-Za-z]+.*$` : finds passwords with **numbers** before letters
- `|` : use OR to find one sequence OR the other
- `.*` : used to find 0 or more characters of **any** type at this position
- `[A-Za-z]+`: used to find 1 or more letters at this position
- `\d+` : used to find 1 or more numbers at this position
- `^` and `$` : **start** and **end** of line respectively

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EzKQEi/1)